# Turn a button into a directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

As the title says, I would like to call the button on a `HTML` page as a custom directive. Like:

```
<buy-button></buy-button>
```

Below is the code I want to transform:

```
<md-button class="md-cornered" 
           ng-disabled="0>=gains" 
           ng-click="buyTaxi()">Buy a Taxi</md-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic transform of your element into a directive. There is no real advantage of doing it but it does what you want:

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfh42jst/)**

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: `<md-button class="md-cornered" ng-disabled="0>=gains" ng-click="buyTaxi()">Buy a Taxi</md-button>`,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

         scope.gains = 1;

         scope.buyTaxi = function () {
            console.log('Buy me a nice taxi!');
         }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Well, the advantage is seen in a cleaner html code and a more structured app.